# How to integrate Selenium and Python

Tags: python

I wanted to run selenium code in using python so, How to integrate with python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can install it using pip:

`pip install selenium`

the documentation has a nice [Getting Started](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) section with some good examples. The example I created below is a very simple one that will load a url and print the page's title. You could use it to just check that everything is up and running.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
print driver.title
driver.close()
```