# automatically edit firefox web address upon pageload, and then reload

Tags: python, firefox

My coding experience is in Python. Is there a simple way to execute a python code in firefox that would detect a particular address, say nytimes.com, load the page, then delete the end of the address following html (this allows bypassing the 20 pageviews/month limit) and reload?

Comment: Do any of the two answers below solve your problem. Please post a comment with issues or accept one of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use selenium as proposed before. Here's a small example how you could do it. Basically the code checks if the limit has been reached and if it has it deletes cookies  and refreshes the page letting you to continue reading. Deleting cookies  lets you read another 10 articles without continuously editing the address. Thats the technical part, you have to consider the legal implications yourself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.nytimes.com')
if browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(.,"You’ve reached the limit of 10 free articles a month.")]'):
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    browser.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use selenium it lets you easily fully control firefox and other web browsers with python. it would only be a few lines of code to acheive this. this answer [How to integrate Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428365/how-to-integrate-selenium-and-python/13429143#13429143) has a working example